# How to fix unreadable highlighted text during search?

Tags: highlight

This is an example of how highlighted text looks in my vim:

[image: vim screenshot]

In the color scheme I am using (/usr/share/vim/vim82/colors/peachpuff.vim) the color is defined like this:

`hi Search term=reverse ctermbg=3 guibg=Gold2`

When I change this particular color using following command:

`:hi Search ctermbg=5`

the color of selection does change (I am using vim from terminal, so `guibg` does not matter). But looks like `term=reverse` value does not affect anything. I expect that `term=reverse` should change the color of text itself, so that the highlighted text would become visible. But the colors of text inside and outside the highlighted area are the same. How can it be fixed?

I am using linux, Mate desktop, vim version 8.2.360

UPDATE:

I ended up specifying `ctremfg` colors in `Search` and several other highlight groups in my vimrc:

`highlight Search term=reverse ctermbg=3 ctermfg=0 guibg=Gold2`

I am very sure that all the colors were somehow readable in vim 8.1, even though definition of `Search` highlight group in the colorscheme I am using (peachbuff) did not change.

Comment: Just because youre in the terminal doesnt mean guibg doesnt apply: what is `:set termguicolor?`. term is used when no colors are available (I think), in this case for reverse video (swap foreground and background, like in less). I would try changing the guibg too, and possible setting the foreground if you can’t read certain colors under the highlighting.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble `set termguicolors?` reports `notermguicolors`. I tried to speciy some guibg like this: `:hi Search ctermbg=3 guibg=Black` - but looks like it affects nothing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. `term` is intended for b&w terminals only. So it has no effect in your case and all you got is a different background. What you want is called `cterm`.
2. `cterm=reverse` actually swaps foreground and background color. So if you highlight `Normal` text with `Search` it effectively becomes `ctermfg=3 ctermbg=fg`. However, it will be different if the "searched" word has some syntax highlighting. Hence I doubt if `reverse` is good for `Search`, but, of course, you can make a try.

P.S. In order never to get background==foreground you can do one of:

a) Something like `hi Search ctermbg=3 ctermfg=bg` (or maybe `ctermfg=fg` depending on new background value), so highlighted text always has same foreground.

b) Just `hi Search cterm=reverse` without specifying any additional color (con: could result in many different colorings due to syntax highlighting).

c) `hi Search ctermfg=bg ctermbg=fg`, so it's always "reversed Normal" (con: "reversed Normal" is often used for "Visual", so it could be confusing).

d) Search harder and find some distinct background color which has good contrast with all syntax elements in this particular color scheme.

Comment: it does not solve my problem, but still very helpful and makes situation more clear!

Comment: @Matt Perhaps you could expand your answer with a specific suggestion on how to set the colors in a way that uses `reverse` properly in order to ensure there's proper contrast? Something like `hi Search cterm=reverse ctermfg=3 ctermfg=NONE` perhaps? That's similar to what OP currently has, but it will use black on yellow background and be readable...